# Regex to delete everything starting with a certain string and followed by anything else?

Tags: excel, vba

the code is working but it doesn't loop through each of the rows to put the answer in its adjacent column. All the column Bs are getting the answer for the last row.

[image]

```
Private Sub simpleRegex()
'Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^[0-9]{1,2}"
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "BSU:.*"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As range
Dim r As range
Set r = ActiveSheet.range("A1", range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.range("A1:A5")

For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))


            'MsgBox (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
        Else
            'MsgBox ("Not matched")
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to keep or delete 'BSU:' itself?

Comment: delete 'BSU:' itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` in the pattern `BSU:*` is applied to the preceding character only so it would match `:` 0 or multiple times.

To match a string starting with `BSU:` and followed by anything use

`BSU:.*`

in which case `.` matches any characters and with `.*` it matches any characters 0 or more number of times which is what you need unless you only want to match what is *after* `BSU:` which also could be done (lookahead or capturing groups).

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the problem.. If I want to delete everything before 'BSU:' will I have to change it to "*.BSU:"

Comment: That would be `.*BSU:`. There are great resources out there online to learn about regular expressions!

Comment: You're welcome, @cookiemonster! Why don't you accept this only answer then?